# Python 2.7 error: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Unit'"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running some code through Spyder (Python 2.7) and it works perfectly well on my colleague's mac, but on my PC I keep getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\eawth\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\iris\analysis\cartography.py", line 44, in <module>
    DEFAULT_SPHERICAL_EARTH_RADIUS_UNIT = cf_units.Unit('m')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Unit'
```

When I click on the error it takes me to a file form the MET office (cartography.py) and line 44 reads:

```
DEFAULT_SPHERICAL_EARTH_RADIUS_UNIT = cf_units.Unit('m')
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this??

Thank you!

[Here is a print screen of the first part of the cartography.py file from the MET Office](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj8Cc.png)

[Here is a print screen of my file which then draws on cartography.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/903CZ.png)

Comment: Can you post more code from cartography.py ?

Comment: Is the file you are trying to run happen to be called `cartography.py`? If so, change it.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyRossi I have added a screen shot of the file that has the error.

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace the file I am running is called CurrentTemp45_Map2 but it draws off code from the MET Office, their file is called cartography.py Dont think I can change the name of their file. Why would this matter though? Sorry I am fairly new to Python.

Comment: Your code seems clean, I can only think of two possible ways that crash your code :

You do not have the latest version of cf_units (which would be weird since the feature that causes problem is actually old)

Or you have another module called cf_units somewhere in your project / in your site_packages.

You should start by installing cf_units again, since you use conda the command would be `conda install -c scitools cf_units`

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyRossi I had tried that and it didn't work. I tried again but still no luck. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something went wrong in my installation. I uninstalled and reinstalled everything and now don't get that error anymore. Thank you.